# Cannot deserialize some tweets using NewtonSoft.Json

Tags: c#-4.0, twitter, console-application, json.net, jsonlint

Hi All,

I am running a C# console app that is using the Twitter Stream API. My code is below

```
 JToken json = JObject.Parse(ResponseStream.ReadLine());
```

For every +- 20 tweets, I get the following error "Error reading JObject from JsonReader".

I copied the json into [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com) and it is valid, so I am perplexed to why this keeps happening. Has anyone else had this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Sometimes the stream returns an empty string. Therefore parsing an empty string will throw an error. An example below on how I protected against it:

```
public static void ProccessTweet(object objMessage)
    {
        if(objMessage.ToString() != "")
        {
            var json = JObject.Parse(objMessage.ToString());
            if (json["retweeted_status"] == null)
            {
                var message = ProcessNewTweet(json);
                Db.Votes.Add(new FNBVote
                {
                    Message = message,
                    Entry = Db.Entries.Find(message.Entry.EntryId)
                });

                return;
            }

            ProcessRetweet(json);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it just started happening recently. I believe it is either a bug with NewtonSoft.Json or a change in the twitter api causing it to send bad jsons. I did a packet capture and found the offending character by counting them, but I didn't see anything wrong. I think we will just have to wait for this bug to be fixed.

**update**
I downgraded Newtonsoft.Json.dll to 4.3.* and it works fine.